# Dynamic height of one div and sibling divs autoheight

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What i have now: [Image](http://s15.postimg.org/gkg6m0pff/gameroom.jpg)

I know is that the height of brown div will be dynamic so i wanted make the other 3 divs (blue, gray and red) adjust/resize to brown div height automatically.
Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Here is some of my code:

```
<div class="row">

    {{--SCORES--}}
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: #2F96B4">
    </div>

    {{--BOARD--}}
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: #8a6d3b">
    </div>

    {{--PLAYERS AND SPECTATORS--}}
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #666666">
    </div>

    {{--CHAT--}}
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Yes, i'm using bootstrap to limit the width of divs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this style:

```
.Row {
    display: table;
}

.Row [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Ref: [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define it as a table:

```
.row { display: table; }
.my_divs { display: table-cell; }
```

where you'd have to add the `.my_divs` class to all four divs

Comment: Didn't work. I tried remove the bootstrap classes and worked. However i need accomplish this with those classes to make sure the website is responsive. So any idea how to do it with bootstrap?